Creating class instances and attributes inside new method
Assume I want to create a class instance only if certain calculation gives positive number, otherwise, return None.
I can create a staticmethod and just use if - else inside... But it is not intuitive why would I not use common instance initialization to create objects. And if I want it to be the only "valid" way to create instances - I would need to raise an Exception inside __init__ method.
I wondered if I could do it differently using __new__. So I made up something like this (simplified example):
class A:
    n_contracts: int

    def __new__(cls, cash: float, margin: float):
        n_contracts = int(cash // margin)

        if n_contracts <= 0:
            return None

        instance = super().__new__(cls)
        instance.n_contracts = n_contracts

        return instance

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"A(n_contracts={self.n_contracts})"


a = A(1000, 100)
print(a)  # prints `A(n_contracts=10)`
try:
    print(A.n_contracts)
except AttributeError as err:
    print(err.name)
b = A(-1000, 100)
print(b)  # prints `None`
A.n_contracts = 100000
print(a)  # prints `A(n_contracts=10)`
c = A(1000, 10)
print(c)  # prints `A(n_contracts=100)`
print(A.n_contracts)  # prints `100000`

Seems like everything working correctly. Is there any downfalls? Because it feels... Uncommon. I'm afraid I just don't see any problem right now, but later it may be a pain to fix, so I want to clarify this to myself.

I'd say the major downside is the surprise and inconsistency with other code. I've never seen class initialization return None before. If initialization should fail, I'd just throw an exception. All returning None is going to do is cause errors relating in None in every case that you forget to explicitly check for None, in which case you'll need to figure out what an AttributeError on None implies is the real problem.

@Carcigenicate It's as intended. My object should have a ClassName|None type, it is used by internal logic and I highly rely on type checker. And as I know, __new__ approach is used to have a control over creation of my object. So... Why wouldn't I use it to determine "should I create it or not"? My only concern is class attribute declaration to make type checker satisfied and possible wierd behavior. But since this class attribute "updates" in __new__... I don't see a problem. So this approach gives me common interface of object creation with desired creation logic. So far I can see...

The usual thing for a __new__ method call in a Python class is to return a working instance of its class.
That is not mandatory, but it is what is strongly expected - and changing it to return  None on failure would almost certainly lead to incorrect usage patterns of your class.
So, for uncommon instantiating patterns, even if you build then into __new__ it would be better to raise an Exception (any exception will do as far as it is a documented behavior - no need for a custom exception class) - - that would prevent one from thinking he has an instance of your class bound to a variable, when the value is actually a None.
And still less surprising, (and therefore could be considered "more correct") would be to prevent direct instantiation of your class at all  using the default __new__  method, and having a custom method (or other call in your project), which will create the instances of your class. The big semantic change there is that for a custom classmethod one has to actually check the project documentation to see what is being returned at each call, and it is free to return  None if it makes sense.
So, besides having a classmethod to instantiate your class, making __new__ fail by default would also be a nice design:
from typing import Self, Never

class A:
    """
    A object that frublonates the eschaton

    ...
    Do not instantiate this directly - call 
    A.new(...)  for new instances
    """
    def __new__(cls) -> Never:
         raise RuntimeError(f"{cls.__name__} can not be instantiated directly. Use {cls.__name__}.new(...)  ")
 
    @classmethod
    def new(cls, cash: float, margin: float) -> Self| None:
         if not (my_condition):
              return None
         # The __new__ method in superclasses won't be using 
         #the custom parameters:
         instance = super().__new__(cls)
         # write the __init__ method as usual, handling
         # the passed in attributes, so that inheritance will work
         # correctly if you need to override it:
         instance.__init__(cash, margin)
         return instance

    def __init__(self, cash: float, margin: float) -> None:
         ...



You forgot the return of instance, but it is really helpful anwer. I still have my doubts... Silently changing behavior can be considered as bad practice but... Ye, it was my intend. I didn't want to create another method and forbid anyone from using common creation syntax <-- silently changed creation behavior, supported by type checker, is it really so bad after this words? And, I assure you, it is completely logically explained and expected by code.
But, I must admit, your example is what my first thought was, so... Obvious choice is more pythonic I guess?) Thank you again!

sorry for the missing return instance  - I've added it now.
For the other things - as stated by me and others: the important factor is the "least surprise". If a __new__ will always fail, it is better than it returning None sometimes, in which case it could work in a few test runs and fail in a production environment, when it would have become an expensive fix.

So __new__ for conditional instance creating is uncommon and is expected to always return an instance of the class, not None. You can make a @classmethod that initializes and returns an instance if n_contracts is positive.
class A:
    def __init__(self, n_contracts: int):
        self.n_contracts = n_contracts

    @classmethod
    def create(cls, cash: float, margin: float):
        n_contracts = int(cash // margin)
        if n_contracts <= 0:
            return None
        return cls(n_contracts)

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"A(n_contracts={self.n_contracts})"

a = A.create(1000, 100)
print(a)  # prints `A(n_contracts=10)`
try:
    print(A.n_contracts)
except AttributeError as err:
    print(err.name)
b = A.create(-1000, 100)
print(b)  # prints `None`
A.n_contracts = 100000
print(a)  # prints `A(n_contracts=10)`
c = A.create(1000, 10)
print(c)  # prints `A(n_contracts=100)`
print(A.n_contracts)  # prints `100000`


This allows you to separate the initialization from the conditional logic.

Well... As I mentioned in my original question, if I want this approach (static|class)method and ensure that noone uses common object initialization (I make this checks for a reason, don't I?) I need to raise exception in __init__. And why would I create another instance of exception handling?
But original question was about: is there any hidden downsides? For example: thread safety,... I literally don't see any, because, this class attributes "updates" in __new__.

@David - yes - you nailed the answer. The onlyextra thing I can thnk of is: if the user doesn't want to ever instantiate this unconditionally, there could be a __new__ method which would raise a RuntimeError in the class, and from the classmethod, one could call super.__new__(cls) instead of cls(...)  directly  - so only the classmethod would ordinarily be able to create new instances.

@Eugene: as for your worry about downsides: there are no technical downside to it: if __new__ would return None, everything would just work as documented. However both @Carcegenicate and David get it very correctly: it is such a surprising behavior it wouldn't be good design at all.
Having a custom method for instantiation (And them a classmethod, not  a static method) is the best approach.

@jsbueno Thank you for the answer. I would appreciate you to make an "answer" so I can mark it accepted.
But I still don't understand what is so surprising? Checks can and should be thrown away into different method(s) so the only difference is "init" -> "new", explicit instance creation and "self" -> "instace"... Is this so... surprising? I literally don't get it.
And why staticmethod should be avoided? I mean... If I need class attributes I would use classmethod, but If I dont - I don't see why is it so bad I should not use it like that?
